# java "Cannot resolve method 'setCharAt(int, char)'"

Tags: java, encryption, error-handling, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a *Caesar cipher* and everything should be working, but I'm getting an error.

Here is my encrypt method:

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText, int rotation) {
    // TODO: implement
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++ ){
        char currentChar = plainText.charAt(i);
        //ASCII 97 == a && 122 == z
        if (currentChar >= 97 && currentChar <= 122){
            char newChar = (char) (currentChar + rotation);
            if(newChar < 97){
                newChar = (char) (97 + (newChar - 122));
            }
            plainText.setCharAt(i, newChar);
        }
    }
    return plainText.toString();
```

After running the code it returns this error:

```
 Error:(26, 26) java: cannot find symbol
 symbol:   method setCharAt(int,char)
 location: variable plainText of type java.lang.String
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `setCharAt` is a method from `StringBuilder`, not from `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [`setCharAt`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/stringbuilder_setcharat.htm) -> you can clearly see it belongs to `StringBuilder` and not `String`.

If you want to *use* it on a `String` you may first create a `StringBuilder` and then call `.toString()` on that object:

```
StringBuilder plainText = new StringBuilder("Some string");
plainText.setCharAt(i, newchar);
String myStr = plainText.toString();
```

It also seems that this is what you were originally planning to do since in the `return` statement you have `plainText.toString()`, and there is no reason to call `toString()` there if it is already a `String` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`setCharAt` in defined for `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`  not on String.

to change a char on string you have to covert it to either char array of a String buffer or builder.

Char array is a decent approach for you as you are playing with each and every character.

Go with the StringBuilder or StringBuffer approach, which will be easy to code, and the readability of the code also will be good.

Use whichever you are comfortable with.